# android: displaying html string and an image

Tags: android, html, image

I want to display in one page the content of an html string and display an image within the same page. I tried it defining a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/home_bg">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/aboutcmkimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:src="@drawable/about"
            android:padding="5dip" />
        <WebView android:id="@+id/aboutcmk" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aboutcmkimage"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is that , the display is coming as two different columns. The html string displayed on first column and image in next column. I want both to come blended and look as a single page . I want the text to come left side of the image and all the space below image . Please help me in achieving this . thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try frame layout or merge. A good example is given here -  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html